# Procedural Terrain Generation Spiking Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I'm getting a problem with my terrain manager where I get these weirdly spiked columns instead of normal terrain (if there is a normal with this kind of generation) any ideas?

**Image :** http://bit.ly/1IVVsET

**Code :**

```
public class TerrainManager : MonoBehaviour, ICameraObserver {

public Terrain mainTerrain;
public float terrainChangeRate = 0.0001f;
public int brushArea = 20;
public static int viewDistance = 9;
public static Vector2 VECTOR_WILDCARD = new Vector2(-10000, -10000);

int resolutionX;
int resolutionY;
float[,] heights;
int heightEdit = 1;

//Chunks
List<Vector2> loadedChunks = new List<Vector2>();
Vector2[] visibleChunks = null;
Terrain[] chunkGraphics = new Terrain[viewDistance];
Vector2 curChunkIndex = new Vector2();
int chunkSizeX = 256;
int chunkSizeY = 256;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    resolutionX = mainTerrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth;
    resolutionY = mainTerrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight;

    heights = mainTerrain.terrainData.GetHeights(0, 0, resolutionX, resolutionY);

    Camera.main.GetComponent<RTSCamera>().Subscribe(this);
    GameObject world = new GameObject();
    world.name = "World";

    for (int i = 0; i < viewDistance; i++)
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject();
        go.name = "Chunk_" + i;
        go.transform.SetParent(world.transform);

        chunkGraphics[i] = go.AddComponent<Terrain>();

        chunkGraphics[i].terrainData = new TerrainData();
        go.AddComponent<TerrainCollider>().terrainData = chunkGraphics[i].terrainData;

        chunkGraphics[i].terrainData.size = new Vector3((int)(chunkSizeX / 4), 600, (int)(chunkSizeY / 4));
        chunkGraphics[i].terrainData.heightmapResolution = (int)(chunkSizeX / 2);
    }
    onCameraMove(Camera.main.transform.position);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            editTerrainHeight(hit.point, terrainChangeRate, brushArea);
        }
    }
}

void editTerrainHeight(Vector3 position, float amount, int diameter)
{
    int terrainPosX = (int)((position.x / mainTerrain.terrainData.size.x) * resolutionX);
    int terrainPosY = (int)((position.z / mainTerrain.terrainData.size.z) * resolutionY);

    float[,] heightChange = new float[diameter, diameter];

    int radius = diameter / 2;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        heightEdit = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        heightEdit = 1;
    }
    amount = amount * heightEdit;

    for (int x = 0; x < diameter; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < diameter; y++)
        {
            int x2 = x - radius;
            int y2 = y - radius;
            heightChange[y, x] = heights[terrainPosY + y2, terrainPosX + x2] + amount;
            heights[terrainPosY + y2, terrainPosX + x2] = heightChange[y, x];
        }
    }

    mainTerrain.terrainData.SetHeights(terrainPosX - radius, terrainPosY - radius, heightChange);
}

public void onCameraMove(Vector3 newCameraPosition)
{
    int chunkIndexX = Mathf.FloorToInt(newCameraPosition.x / chunkSizeX);
    int chunkIndexY = Mathf.FloorToInt(newCameraPosition.z / chunkSizeY);

    if (curChunkIndex.x == chunkIndexX && curChunkIndex.y == chunkIndexY)
    {
        return;
    }

    curChunkIndex.x = chunkIndexX;
    curChunkIndex.y = chunkIndexY;

    Vector2[] newVisibleChunks = new Vector2[viewDistance];

    newVisibleChunks[0] = new Vector2(chunkIndexX - 1, chunkIndexY +1);
    newVisibleChunks[1] = new Vector2(chunkIndexX, chunkIndexY +1);
    newVisibleChunks[2] = new Vector2(chunkIndexX + 1, chunkIndexY +1);

    newVisibleChunks[3] = new Vector2(chunkIndexX -1, chunkIndexY);
    newVisibleChunks[4] = new Vector2(chunkIndexX, chunkIndexY);
    newVisibleChunks[5] = new Vector2(chunkIndexX + 1, chunkIndexY);

    newVisibleChunks[6] = new Vector2(chunkIndexX - 1, chunkIndexY -1);
    newVisibleChunks[7] = new Vector2(chunkIndexX, chunkIndexY -1);
    newVisibleChunks[8] = new Vector2(chunkIndexX + 1, chunkIndexY -1);

    Terrain[] newChunkGraphics = new Terrain[viewDistance];
    List<int> freeTerrains = new List<int>();
    List<int> loadingIndexes = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < viewDistance; i++)
    {
        bool found = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < viewDistance; j++)
        {
            if (visibleChunks == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (newVisibleChunks[i].Equals(visibleChunks[j]))
            {
                visibleChunks[j] = VECTOR_WILDCARD;
                newChunkGraphics[i] = chunkGraphics[j];

                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            loadingIndexes.Add(i);
        }
    }

    if (visibleChunks != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < viewDistance; i++)
        {
            if (visibleChunks[i] != VECTOR_WILDCARD)
            {
                freeTerrains.Add(i);
                saveChunkToMemory(chunkGraphics[i], visibleChunks[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < viewDistance; i++)
        {
                freeTerrains.Add(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < loadingIndexes.Count; i++)
    {
        loadChunkFromMemory(newVisibleChunks[loadingIndexes[i]], freeTerrains[i]);
        newChunkGraphics[loadingIndexes[i]] = chunkGraphics[freeTerrains[i]];
    }

    visibleChunks = newVisibleChunks;
    chunkGraphics = newChunkGraphics;
}

void loadChunkFromMemory(Vector2 cordIndex, int graphicIndex)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (Vector2 v in loadedChunks)
    {
        if (v == cordIndex)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    GameObject terrainGO;
    if (!found)
    {
        terrainGO = generateChunk(cordIndex, graphicIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        //Load Chunk from Memory
        Debug.Log("Loading Chunk(" + cordIndex.x + "," + cordIndex.y + ")");

        terrainGO = chunkGraphics[graphicIndex].gameObject;
    }

    terrainGO.transform.position = new Vector3(chunkSizeX * cordIndex.x, 0, chunkSizeY * cordIndex.y);


}

GameObject generateChunk(Vector2 cordIndex, int graphicIndex)
{
    GameObject terrainGO = chunkGraphics[graphicIndex].gameObject;

    loadedChunks.Add(cordIndex);

    setTerrainHeightMap(terrainGO.GetComponent<Terrain>(), cordIndex);

    return terrainGO;
}

void setTerrainHeightMap(Terrain terrain, Vector2 cordIndex)
{
    float[,] heights = new float[terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight, terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth];

    heights[0, 0] = 0.5f;
    heights[terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth - 1, 0] = 0.5f;
    heights[0, terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight - 1] = 0.5f;
    heights[terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth - 1, terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight - 1] = 0.5f;

    heights = diamondSquare(heights, 0, 0, terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth - 1, 0);

    terrain.terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);
}

float[,] getTerrainHeightMap(Vector2 cordIndex)
{
      return null;
}

float[,] diamondSquare(float[,] heights, int offSetX, int offSetY, int squareSize, int depth)
{
    if (squareSize == 1)
    {
        return heights;
    }

    float topLeft = heights[offSetY, offSetX];
    float topRight = heights[offSetY, offSetX + squareSize];
    float bottomLeft = heights[offSetY + squareSize, offSetX];
    float bottomRight = heights[offSetY + squareSize, offSetX + squareSize];

    int size = squareSize / 2;

    if (topLeft == 0 || topRight == 0 || bottomLeft == 0 || bottomRight == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("One or more Corner Seeds have not been set..");
    }

    if (heights[offSetY + size, offSetX + size] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY + size, offSetX + size] = getRandomHeight(depth + (int)averagePoints(topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight));
    }
    float centrePoint = heights[offSetY + size, offSetX + size];

    //left Diamond
    float runningAverage = averagePoints(topLeft, centrePoint, bottomLeft);

    if (offSetX - size > 0 && heights[offSetY + size, offSetX - size] != 0)
    {
        runningAverage = averagePoints(topLeft, centrePoint, bottomLeft, heights[offSetY + size, offSetX - size]);
    }

    if (heights[offSetY + size, offSetX] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY + size, offSetX] = runningAverage + getRandomHeight(depth);
    }

    //right Diamond
    runningAverage = averagePoints(topRight, centrePoint, bottomRight);

    if (offSetX + (squareSize * 1.5f) < heights.GetLength(1) && heights[offSetY + size, offSetX + (int)(squareSize * 1.5f)] != 0)
    {
        runningAverage = averagePoints(topRight, centrePoint, bottomRight, heights[offSetY + size, offSetX + (int)(squareSize * 1.5f)]);
    }

    if (heights[offSetY + size, offSetX + squareSize] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY + size, offSetX + squareSize] = runningAverage + getRandomHeight(depth);
    }

    //top Diamond
    runningAverage = averagePoints(topLeft, centrePoint, topRight);

    if (offSetY - size > 0 && heights[offSetY - size, offSetX + size] != 0)
    {
        runningAverage = averagePoints(topLeft, centrePoint, topRight, heights[offSetY - size, offSetX + size]);
    }

    if (heights[offSetY, offSetX + size] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY, offSetX + size] = runningAverage + getRandomHeight(depth);
    }

    //bottom Diamond
    runningAverage = averagePoints(bottomRight, centrePoint, bottomLeft);

    if (offSetY + (squareSize * 1.5f) < heights.GetLength(0) && heights[offSetY + (int)(squareSize * 1.5f), offSetX + size] != 0)
    {
        runningAverage = averagePoints(bottomRight, centrePoint, topRight, heights[offSetY + (int)(squareSize * 1.5f), offSetX + size]);
    }

    if (heights[offSetY + squareSize, offSetX + size] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY + squareSize, offSetX + size] = runningAverage + getRandomHeight(depth);
    }

    heights = diamondSquare(heights, offSetX, offSetY, size, depth + 1);
    heights = diamondSquare(heights, offSetX + size, offSetY, size, depth + 1);
    heights = diamondSquare(heights, offSetX, offSetY + size, size, depth + 1);
    heights = diamondSquare(heights, offSetX + size, offSetY + size, size, depth + 1);

    return heights;

 }

float averagePoints(float p1, float p2, float p3, float p4)
{
    return (p1 + p2 + p3 + p4) * 0.25f;
}

float averagePoints(float p1, float p2, float p3)
{
    return (p1 + p2 + p3) * 0.3333f;
}

float getRandomHeight(int depth)
{
    return Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.0f) / Mathf.Pow(2, depth);
}

void saveChunkToMemory(Terrain chunk, Vector2 index)
{
    Debug.Log("Unloading Chunk(" + index.x + "," + index.y + ")");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few more hours here is a fix :D

```
public class TerrainManager : MonoBehaviour, ICameraObserver {

public Terrain mainTerrain;
public float terrainChangeRate = 0.0001f;
public int brushArea = 20;
public static int viewDistance = 9;
public static Vector2 VECTOR_WILDCARD = new Vector2(-10000, -10000);

int resolutionX;
int resolutionY;
float[,] heights;
int heightEdit = 1;

//Chunks
List<Vector2> loadedChunks = new List<Vector2>();
Vector2[] visibleChunks = null;
Terrain[] chunkGraphics = new Terrain[viewDistance];
Vector2 curChunkIndex = new Vector2();
int chunkSizeX = 256;
int chunkSizeY = 256;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    resolutionX = mainTerrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth;
    resolutionY = mainTerrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight;

    heights = mainTerrain.terrainData.GetHeights(0, 0, resolutionX, resolutionY);

    Camera.main.GetComponent<RTSCamera>().Subscribe(this);
    GameObject world = new GameObject();
    world.name = "World";

    for (int i = 0; i < viewDistance; i++)
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject();
        go.name = "Chunk_" + i;
        go.transform.SetParent(world.transform);

        chunkGraphics[i] = go.AddComponent<Terrain>();

        chunkGraphics[i].terrainData = new TerrainData();
        go.AddComponent<TerrainCollider>().terrainData = chunkGraphics[i].terrainData;

        chunkGraphics[i].terrainData.size = new Vector3((int)(chunkSizeX / 4), 600, (int)(chunkSizeY / 4));
        chunkGraphics[i].terrainData.heightmapResolution = (int)(chunkSizeX / 2);
    }
    onCameraMove(Camera.main.transform.position);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            editTerrainHeight(hit.point, terrainChangeRate, brushArea);
        }
    }
}

void editTerrainHeight(Vector3 position, float amount, int diameter)
{
    int terrainPosX = (int)((position.x / mainTerrain.terrainData.size.x) * resolutionX);
    int terrainPosY = (int)((position.z / mainTerrain.terrainData.size.z) * resolutionY);

    float[,] heightChange = new float[diameter, diameter];

    int radius = diameter / 2;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        heightEdit = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        heightEdit = 1;
    }
    amount = amount * heightEdit;

    for (int x = 0; x < diameter; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < diameter; y++)
        {
            int x2 = x - radius;
            int y2 = y - radius;
            heightChange[y, x] = heights[terrainPosY + y2, terrainPosX + x2] + amount;
            heights[terrainPosY + y2, terrainPosX + x2] = heightChange[y, x];
        }
    }

    mainTerrain.terrainData.SetHeights(terrainPosX - radius, terrainPosY - radius, heightChange);
}

public void onCameraMove(Vector3 newCameraPosition)
{
    //Debug.Log ("Camera Moved");
    int chunkIndexX = Mathf.FloorToInt (newCameraPosition.x / chunkSizeX);
    int chunkIndexY = Mathf.FloorToInt (newCameraPosition.z / chunkSizeY);

    if (curChunkIndex.x == chunkIndexX && curChunkIndex.y == chunkIndexY) {

        return;
    }

    curChunkIndex.x = chunkIndexX;
    curChunkIndex.y = chunkIndexY;

    //Debug.Log ("Chunk Index ( " + chunkIndexX + ", " + chunkIndexY + " )");

    Vector2[] newVisibleChunks = new Vector2[9];

    newVisibleChunks [0] = new Vector2 (chunkIndexX -1, chunkIndexY +1);
    newVisibleChunks [1] = new Vector2 (chunkIndexX, chunkIndexY +1);
    newVisibleChunks [2] = new Vector2 (chunkIndexX +1, chunkIndexY +1);

    newVisibleChunks [3] = new Vector2 (chunkIndexX -1, chunkIndexY);
    newVisibleChunks [4] = new Vector2 (chunkIndexX, chunkIndexY);
    newVisibleChunks [5] = new Vector2 (chunkIndexX +1, chunkIndexY);

    newVisibleChunks [6] = new Vector2 (chunkIndexX -1, chunkIndexY -1);
    newVisibleChunks [7] = new Vector2 (chunkIndexX, chunkIndexY -1);
    newVisibleChunks [8] = new Vector2 (chunkIndexX +1, chunkIndexY -1);


    Terrain[] newChunkGraphics = new Terrain[chunkGraphics.Length]; 
    List<int> freeTerrains = new List<int>();
    List<int> loadingIndexes = new List<int>();
    //List<int> newIndex = new List<int>();


    for (int i =0; i <9; i++) {
        bool found =  false;
        for (int j =0; j <9; j++) {

            if (visibleChunks == null)
                break;

            if (newVisibleChunks[i].Equals (visibleChunks[j])){

                visibleChunks[j] = VECTOR_WILDCARD;
                newChunkGraphics[i] = chunkGraphics[j];
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found){
            loadingIndexes.Add (i);
        }
    }



    if (visibleChunks != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i< 9; i++) {

            if (visibleChunks [i] != VECTOR_WILDCARD) {

                freeTerrains.Add (i);
                saveChunkToMemory (chunkGraphics [i], visibleChunks [i]);


            }
        }
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i< 9; i++) {

                freeTerrains.Add (i);

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < loadingIndexes.Count; i++) {
        newChunkGraphics[loadingIndexes[i]] = chunkGraphics[freeTerrains[i]];

    }
    visibleChunks = newVisibleChunks;
    chunkGraphics = newChunkGraphics;

    for (int i = 0; i < loadingIndexes.Count; i++) {

        loadChunkFromMemory(visibleChunks[loadingIndexes[i]], loadingIndexes[i]);


    }


}

void loadChunkFromMemory(Vector2 cordIndex, int graphicIndex)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (Vector2 v in loadedChunks)
    {
        if (v == cordIndex)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    GameObject terrainGO;
    if (!found)
    {
        terrainGO = generateChunk(cordIndex, graphicIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        //Load Chunk from Memory
        Debug.Log("Loading Chunk(" + cordIndex.x + "," + cordIndex.y + ")");

        terrainGO = chunkGraphics[graphicIndex].gameObject;
    }

    terrainGO.transform.position = new Vector3(chunkSizeX * cordIndex.x, 0, chunkSizeY * cordIndex.y);


}

GameObject generateChunk(Vector2 cordIndex, int graphicIndex)
{
    GameObject terrainGO = chunkGraphics[graphicIndex].gameObject;

    loadedChunks.Add(cordIndex);

    setTerrainHeightMap(terrainGO.GetComponent<Terrain>(), cordIndex);

    return terrainGO;
}

void setTerrainHeightMap(Terrain terrain, Vector2 cordIndex)
{
    float[,] heights = new float[terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight, terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth];

    bool left = false;
    bool right = false;
    bool top = false;
    bool bottom = false;

    //left
    float[,] hm = getTerrainHeightMap(new Vector2(cordIndex.x - 1, cordIndex.y));
    if(hm != null)
    {
        left = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < hm.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            heights[i, 0] = hm[i, hm.GetLength(1) - 1];
        }
    }
    //Right
    hm = getTerrainHeightMap(new Vector2(cordIndex.x + 1, cordIndex.y));
    if (hm != null)
    {
        right = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < hm.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            heights[i, heights.GetLength(1) - 1] = hm[i, 0];
        }
    }

    hm = getTerrainHeightMap(new Vector2(cordIndex.x, cordIndex.y - 1));
    if (hm != null)
    {
        top = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < hm.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            heights[i, 0] = hm[hm.GetLength(0) - 1, i];
        }
    }

    hm = getTerrainHeightMap(new Vector2(cordIndex.x, cordIndex.y + 1));
    if (hm != null)
    {
        bottom = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < hm.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            heights[heights.GetLength(1) - 1, i] = hm [0, i];
        }
    }

    if (!top && !left)
    {
        heights[0, 0] = 0.2f;
    }
    if (!bottom && !left)
    {
        heights[terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight - 1, 0] = 0.2f;
    }
    if (!top && !right)
    {
        heights[0, terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth - 1] = 0.2f;
    }
    if (!bottom && !right)
    {
        heights[terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight - 1, terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth - 1] = 0.2f;
    }

    heights[0, 0] = 0.2f;
    heights[terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight - 1, 0] = 0.2f;
    heights[0, terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth - 1] = 0.2f;
    heights[terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight - 1, terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth - 1] = 0.2f;

    heights = diamondSquare(heights, 0, 0, terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth - 1, 0);

    terrain.terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);
}

float[,] getTerrainHeightMap(Vector2 cordIndex)
{

    if (loadedChunks.Contains(cordIndex))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < visibleChunks.Length; i++)
        {
            if (visibleChunks[i].x == cordIndex.x && visibleChunks[i].y == cordIndex.y)
            {
                return chunkGraphics[i].terrainData.GetHeights(0, 0, chunkGraphics[i].terrainData.heightmapWidth, chunkGraphics[i].terrainData.heightmapWidth);
            }
        }

        return loadHeightMapFromMemory(cordIndex);
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }

}

float[,] loadHeightMapFromMemory(Vector2 cordIndex)
{
    return null;
}

float[,] diamondSquare(float[,] heights, int offSetX, int offSetY, int squareSize, int depth)
{
    if (squareSize == 1)
        return heights;


    float topLeft = heights[offSetY, offSetX];
    float topRight = heights[offSetY, offSetX + squareSize];
    float bottomLeft = heights[offSetY + squareSize, offSetX];
    float bottomRight = heights[offSetY + squareSize, offSetX + squareSize];

    if (topLeft == 0 || topRight == 0 || bottomLeft == 0 || bottomRight == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("One or more Corner Seed Values is not set");
    }

    if (heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX + (squareSize / 2)] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX + (squareSize / 2)] = getRandomHeight(depth) + averagePoints(topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight);
    }

    float centrePoint = heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX + (squareSize / 2)];
    //left diamond
    float runningAverage = averagePoints(topLeft, centrePoint, bottomLeft);

    if (offSetX - (squareSize / 2) > 0 && heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX - (squareSize / 2)] != 0)
    {

        runningAverage = averagePoints(topLeft, centrePoint, bottomLeft, heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX - (squareSize / 2)]);

    }

    if (heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX] = runningAverage + getRandomHeight(depth);
    }
    //right diamond
    runningAverage = averagePoints(topRight, centrePoint, bottomRight);

    if (offSetX + (squareSize * 1.5f) < heights.GetLength(1) && heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX + (int)(squareSize * 1.5f)] != 0)
    {

        runningAverage = averagePoints(topRight, centrePoint, bottomRight, heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX + (int)(squareSize * 1.5f)]);

    }

    if (heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX + squareSize] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY + (squareSize / 2), offSetX + squareSize] = runningAverage + getRandomHeight(depth);
    }
    //top diamond
    runningAverage = averagePoints(topLeft, centrePoint, topRight);

    if (offSetY - (squareSize / 2) > 0 && heights[offSetY - (squareSize / 2), offSetX + (squareSize / 2)] != 0)
    {

        runningAverage = averagePoints(topLeft, centrePoint, topRight, heights[offSetY - (squareSize / 2), offSetX + (squareSize / 2)]);

    }

    if (heights[offSetY, offSetX + (squareSize / 2)] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY, offSetX + (squareSize / 2)] = runningAverage + getRandomHeight(depth);
    }
    //bottom diamond
    runningAverage = averagePoints(bottomRight, centrePoint, bottomLeft);

    if (offSetY + (int)(squareSize * 1.5f) < heights.GetLength(0) && heights[offSetY + (int)(squareSize * 1.5f), offSetX + (squareSize / 2)] != 0)
    {

        runningAverage = averagePoints(bottomRight, centrePoint, topRight, heights[offSetY + (int)(squareSize * 1.5f), offSetX + (squareSize / 2)]);

    }

    if (heights[offSetY + squareSize, offSetX + (squareSize / 2)] == 0)
    {
        heights[offSetY + squareSize, offSetX + (squareSize / 2)] = runningAverage + getRandomHeight(depth);
    }

    heights = diamondSquare(heights, offSetX, offSetY, squareSize / 2, depth + 1);//top left
    heights = diamondSquare(heights, offSetX + (squareSize / 2), offSetY, squareSize / 2, depth + 1);//top right
    heights = diamondSquare(heights, offSetX, offSetY + (squareSize / 2), squareSize / 2, depth + 1);//bottom left
    heights = diamondSquare(heights, offSetX + (squareSize / 2), offSetY + (squareSize / 2), squareSize / 2, depth + 1);//bottom right'

    return heights;

 }

float averagePoints(float p1, float p2, float p3, float p4)
{
    return (p1 + p2 + p3 + p4) / 4;
}

float averagePoints(float p1, float p2, float p3)
{
    return (p1 + p2 + p3) / 3;
}

float getRandomHeight(int depth)
{
    return Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f) / Mathf.Pow(2, depth);
}

void saveChunkToMemory(Terrain chunk, Vector2 index)
{
    Debug.Log("Unloading Chunk(" + index.x + "," + index.y + ")");
}
```